# Angular2 dynamiccomponentloader parameters for @Output

Tags: input, angular, output, eventemitter

To my understanding, the way you set @Input variables for the component you just added to the DOM with DynamicComponentLoader, is that you use the promise block after invoking something like loadIntoLocation:

```
this.dcl.loadIntoLocation( Lorem, this.elRef, 'target')
            .then( cmpRef => {

                cmpRef.instance.foo = _self.baz;
            });


export class Lorem {
    public @Input()  foo : String;
    ...
```

My questions is how do you set the @Output when using dynamiccomponentloader?

```
this.dcl.loadIntoLocation( Lorem, this.elRef, 'target')
            .then( cmpRef => {

                cmpRef.instance.foo = _self.baz;
                cmpRef.instance.changer = _self.change($event);
            });



export class Lorem {
    public @Input()  foo            : String;
           @Output() changer = new EventEmitter();
    ...
    ...
    this.changer.emit("event");
```

I am very grateful for help you could offer.

Comment: Components added by `DynamicComponentLoader` don't support `@Input()` and `@Output()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leverage **subscribe** method instead link to result of _self.change($event) function like following:

```
cmpRef.instance.changer.subscribe(($event) => _self.change($event));
```

Since beta.16 loadIntoLocation was removed, in my example i will use loadNextToLocation wich takes a ViewContainerRef.

*App component*

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div #target></div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  baz: string = "Test string";
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target : ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(Lorem, this.target)
      .then(cmpRef => {
        cmpRef.instance.foo = this.baz;
        cmpRef.instance.changer.subscribe(($event) => this.change($event));
      });
  }
  change($event) {
    alert($event);
  }
}
```

*Lorem component*

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lorem',
  template: `
  <div>{{foo}}</div>
  <button (click)="run()">Run</button>`
})
class Lorem {
  @Input() foo: String;
  @Output() changer = new EventEmitter();
  run() {
    this.changer.emit("event from child");
  }
}
```

See [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWd3W99Rl5tHJOdCDQWc?p=preview)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: many thnx for your help - My code is now working. I have two questions before I close this post though:

Comment: (1) if baz was an object instead of a string, would it be the same object (if later edited) that lorem accesses?: cmpRef.instance.foo = this.baz; aka @Input() foo: Object;

Comment: (2) Is it a closed "channel" between each parent instance and each child lorem, where no other instantiations of the parent component can "listen in" ? I have concerns about too many messages in my app and I prefer your recommendation (if closed) than implementing a listener that has a verification if condition. ie this._emitterexample.subscribe( args => { if( args.id === this.localvar ) { ... callback ... } } );

Comment: 1) If baz will be object and later edited (ie this.baz.property = 'test2') then each child will be same object. If you want different object for each child after editing baz object then you need to use immutable param (ie cmpRef.instance.foo = { this.baz.property }) 2) each call of loadNextToLocation from parent initiate new 'channel' for new instance of child component. We can say that it is a closed channel

Comment: encapsulated channel i suppose. but it sounds like no drifting signals which is cool - thank you greatly for your help yurzui